# Can't solve system of six equations in five variables

Tags: equation-solving

Here's an equations from mechanics:

```
eq1 := Xa2 + Xb2 - (m1 + m2)*g*Sin[φ] + Fc == 0
eq2 := Ya2 + Yb2 - (m1 + m2)*g*Cos[φ] - Fe - F1 + Fr*Sin[α] == 0
eq3 := Za2 + Fr*Cos[α] == 0
eq4 := Yb2*2*R - F1*R - Fe*(R - x*Cos[α]) + Fr*R*Sin[α] - (R*m1 + m2*(Rx*Cos[α]))*g*Cos[φ] == 0
eq5 := -Xb2*2*R - Fc*(R - x*Cos[α]) - (R*m1 + m2*(R - x*Cos[α]))*g*Sin[φ] == 0
eq6 := Mvr - Fc*x*Sin[α] - g*Sin[φ]*(4*R/(3*π)*m1 + m2*x*Sin[α]) == 0
Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6}, {Xa2, Xb2, Ya2, Yb2, Za2}]
```

Answer from book is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq1 := Xa2 + Xb2 - (m1 + m2)*g*Sin[φ] + Fc == 0;
eq2 := Ya2 + Yb2 - (m1 + m2)*g*Cos[φ] - Fe - F1 + 
    Fr*Sin[α] == 0;
eq3 := Za2 + Fr*Cos[α] == 0;
eq4 := Yb2*2*R - F1*R - Fe*(R*x*Cos[α]) +
    Fr*R*Sin[α] - (R*m1 + m2*(Rx*Cos[α]))*g*Cos[φ] == 
   0;
eq5 := -Xb2*2*R - Fc*(R - x*Cos[α]) -
    (R*m1 + m2*(R - x*Cos[α]))*g*Sin[φ] == 0;
eq6 := Mvr - Fc*x*Sin[α] -
    g*Sin[φ]*(4*R/(3*π)*m1 + m2*x*Sin[α]) == 0;

Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6}, {Xa2, Xb2, Ya2, Yb2, Za2}]

(* {} *)
```

The system is overdetermined. Looking at the [`Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html) for [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
Options[Solve]

(* {Cubics -> Automatic, GeneratedParameters -> C, InverseFunctions -> Automatic,
  MaxExtraConditions -> 0, Method -> Automatic, Modulus -> 0, 
 Quartics -> Automatic, VerifySolutions -> Automatic, 
 WorkingPrecision -> ∞} *)
```

Then specifically at the option [`MaxExtraConditions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html)

```
?MaxExtraConditions
```

[image]

```
(sol = Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6}, {Xa2, Xb2, Ya2, Yb2, Za2}, 
     MaxExtraConditions -> 1][[1]]) // Column
```

[image]

Each [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) has the same condition

```
assume = sol[[All, -1, -1]] // Union

(* {-3 Mvr π + 3 Fc π x Sin[α] + 4 g m1 R Sin[φ] + 
   3 g m2 π x Sin[α] Sin[φ] == 0} *)
```

To eliminate the condition, you can either [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) using this assumption or use [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html)

```
(soln = sol // Normal) // Column
```

[image]

To solve for `Xa2` and `Ya2` in terms of `Xb2` and `Yb2`

```
(soln2 = Solve[soln[[1 ;; 4]] /. Rule :> Equal, {Xa2, Ya2}, {R, x}][[1]] // 
    Simplify) // Column
```

[image]

Comment: After changing the third equation to `eq3 := Za2 - Fr*Cos[α] == 0` and executing all of the code, I do not get an error message. What error message are you getting?